# ... is all and any

Tags: grammar, phrases, adjectives

From my daughter's homework:

- The yellow monster is happy.
- The brown monster is serious.
- The green monster is joyous.
- The rainbow monster is...

would "all and any" work? "Any" on its own does not sound right, or does it?

Comment: Brown not being a colour of the spectrum, one might suspect a trick question. _Ambivalent_? From an ELU perspective, '... any or all of the above' sounds more idiomatic.

Comment: Either supporting the NHS, or of a sexual inclination that I hesitate to name on this list?

Comment: The question is unanswerable. Nothing follows about the rainbow monster from the qualities of the single-coloured ones.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A rather silly question. Yellow, green and brown are all colours covering parts of the spectrum of visible light, although brown is not a traditional spectral colour and is usually associated with some darkening of the yellow, red and orange that it comprises. The rainbow contains all visible wavelengths, some of which are not in yellow, green and brown. But where does this knowledge lead us? Nowhere useful for answering the question.

All that may be said is that the rainbow monster is all these and more.

Comment: yes... it looks like "all of these" would be most suitable....

Comment: That said... ending all of these precludes the use of the sentence in isolation. You can say in isolation "the yellow monster is happy".... I am wondering if there is an adjective that has the meaning of "any" but can be used without prior context...

Comment: @Glen, why do you assume that the colour of a monster's skin or fur is causally connected with the monster's mood? Maybe this yellow monster just **happens to be** happy; this in no way entails that the presence of yellow among the colours of another monster will be accompanied by happiness.